# Where is the sampling integrator in version 3.6?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, versions

Where is the sampling integrator in version 3.6? I can find it in older versions but it seems to have disappeared in 3.6. Thanks.

Comment: I believe it was removed as unnecessary when CyclesX was introduced in Blender 3.0. Can't find any docs to confirm that now though. It's certainly there in 2.93 but not in 3.3 LTS.

Comment: [Here's](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/render/cycles/render_settings/sampling.html#sampling) a link to the 2.93 Sampling section of the Manual and [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/render/cycles/render_settings/sampling.html#sampling) is the one for 3.0 with all later versions being the same.

Answer (score 3):

This option has been removed since 3.0. In Blender 2.x under the *Integrator* option you can select between *Path Tracing* and *Branched Path Tracing*. Branched path tracing has been removed with 3.0, see [here](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Cycles) under section **Removed Features and Compatibility**

> Branched path tracing was removed. We recommend using adaptive sampling to automatically allocate more samples where needed.

and an *Integrator* option with only one setting is pretty useless.

This is also in line with what @JohnEason pointed out, the [manual for 2.93](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/render/cycles/render_settings/sampling.html#adaptive-sampling) explains the *Integrator* option while from [3.0 upwards](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/render/cycles/render_settings/sampling.html) the part has been removed (i double checked 3.0, no *Integrator* option anymore). Afaik they integrated *CyclesX* into 3.0 which had major changes under the hood. [This blog section](https://code.blender.org/2021/04/cycles-x/#deprecation) confirms the same:

> Branched path tracing. We are working to improve sampling algorithms to make this obsolete, and more automatically assign samples where needed. Improved adaptive sampling and light importance sampling are key here.

> These features will remain available and supported in 2.83 and 2.93 LTS releases.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean CMJ, it was removed in Blender 3.0. Cf https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Cycles